# Provisioning profile misses entitlements

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I am trying to sign a ipa and upload it to TestFlight using Xcode 14.3

I open the xarchive in XCode using

```
open /Users/alessandrolipa/IdeaProjects/nutmeg-flutter/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive
```

and then I let Xcode automatically sign. However the final app doesn't have all entitlements I set in the apple developer portal (notifications, apple sign-in, universal links).

As far as I understand, the problem is in the provisioning profile. So I go check what entitlements are in the profile used.

```
security cms -D -i ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/db61034b-08e0-4ce5-afa9-d4f603cb1294.mobileprovision
```

and indeed I see the Entitlements missing.

```
 <key>Entitlements</key>
        <dict>
                <key>beta-reports-active</key>
                <true/>
                                
                                <key>aps-environment</key>
                <string>production</string>
                                
                                <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
                <string>*</string>
                                
                                <key>application-identifier</key>
                <string>CN7XB83K76.com.nutmeg.app</string>
                                
                                <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
                <array>
                                <string>CN7XB83K76.*</string>
                                <string>com.apple.token</string>
                </array>
                                
                                <key>get-task-allow</key>
                <false/>
                                
                                <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
                <string>CN7XB83K76</string>
                                
                                <key>com.apple.developer.applesignin</key>
                <array>
                                <string>Default</string>
                </array>
                
        </dict>
```

I tried to recreate the profile manually, delete existing profiles and re-run Xcode with automatic profile, destroy the certificates and recreate it but nothing.

I also have entitlements set in the app under `Runner/RunnerRelease.entitlements` which are correctly populated and correctly pointed in the Xcode settings.

I am not sure what else to try